# Smart app banner is still displaying in safari even i removed the meta tag

Tags: html, safari, mobile-safari

I have removed this meta tag from my code

I also inspected the page source and i cannot see this tag in my page source but when i open my website the app banner is still visible in safari.
I am only facing this issue in safari.
Working fine is chrome.

This is the meta tag which i removed :

Comment: <meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=ssssssssssssss">

Comment: did you ever get an answer for this?

Comment: could be because you have setup universal links for your domain / app